# What does ">>" do?

Tags: java, c++, binary, arduino, conditional-statements

can somebody explain how does this condition work and why?
I have look evrywhere but i can't find an answer, just examples that uses it but without explaining it.

```
if((i>>j)&1==1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Search for bit manipulation & shifting.

Comment: Here's a SO link on [bit shifting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting)

Answer (score 0):

It's the [bitwise right-shift operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Right_shift_.3E.3E).

It shifts each bit in its left operand to the right by the number of bits dictated by the right operand.

For example:

```
int a = 6;      // binary 0110
int b = a >> 1; // binary 0011, which is 3 in decimal.
```